# How to find binary data within ConstBitStream starting from a given offset?

Tags: python, bitstring, bitstream

I'm trying to find specific bytes within a file loaded as ConstBitStream:

```
s = ConstBitStream(filename=myFile)
found = s.find('0x4140', bytealigned=False)
```

This is working fine for the first occurrence. After finding the first sequence, I want to find the next one by using the `find` method again but starting from an offset now:

```
s.bytepos = position_after_the_first_occurrence + my_offset
found = s.find('0x4140', start=s.bytepos, bytealigned=False)
```

This doesn't seem to work. I'm always getting the position from the first occurrence of my binary sequence.

What's wrong?

---

UPDATE:

(values of first `found` and `s.bytepos`):

```
found = {tuple} (54784, )
s.bytepos = {int} 6848
```

(values of second `found` and `s.bytepos`):

```
s.bytepos = {int} 32969
found = {tuple} (54784, )
```

It seems that setting `start=s.bytepos` does not have any effect.

Comment: Can you print out the values of `found` (the first value) and `s.bytepos`?

Comment: Don't use `s.bytepos` as a value for `start` argument, use `s.pos` instead.

Comment: Be sure that `my_offset` counts bytes, not bits. Be aware that `found` value is a tuple with bit offset, not byte offset.

Comment: s.pos solved the problem but did not work in my case anyway. i wrote my own search algorithm. you should write this as an answer so i can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `start` parameter is the bit position to start the search, not the byte position. To get the next occurrence you need to use `start=s.bitpos + 1`.

Another thing to note is that if you use `bytealigned=False` (which is the default) then you can't in general even use `s.bytepos` afterwards as the current position might not be byte aligned (it will raise a `ByteAlignError`). Chances are you want `bytealigned=True`, which is also a fair bit faster.

Also note you can just use

```
g = s.findall('0x4140')
```

which returns a generator that gives all the positions without having to do multiple `find` calls (just use `g.next()` repeatedly or `list(g)` to get them all at once).